# CSV file contains empty line in the last

Tags: java, csv, jackson-dataformat-csv

I am writing a list of object to CSV file using jackson-dataformat-csv lib. But when I open it, there is an empty line in the last. How can I remove this line when writting? Below is my code.

```
public static void writeAccountToFile(List<Map<String, Object>> list, String filePath) {
    System.out.println("Write data to csv file start");
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
        CsvSchema schema = null;
        CsvSchema.Builder schemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            for (String col : list.get(0).keySet()) {
                schemaBuilder.addColumn(col);
            }   
        } else {
              schemaBuilder.addColumn("test1");
              schemaBuilder.addColumn("test2");
        }
        schema = schemaBuilder.build().withLineSeparator("\r").withHeader();
        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        mapper.configure(CsvGenerator.Feature.STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING, true);
        mapper.writer(schema).writeValues(writer).writeAll(list);
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: It's not clear: is your code producing `<CSV_DATA_LINE>\n` OR `<CSV_DATA_LINE>\n\n`?

Comment: @fluffy for example this is my result csv file:

    line 1: "acc", "name"
    line 2: "111", "test"
    line 3: "222", "test2"
    line 4:

Comment: I can't understand anything of that. Could you please not use comments for that but rather edit your question providing an example CSV file output? Additionally, **what** I really asked is, is your result file ending with single or double `\n` (essentially `\n` or `\n\n`; or `\r\n` vs `\r\n\r\n` if CRLF is a part of the CSV standard)?

Comment: @fluffy it is \r\n in windows

Comment: I _guess_ you're just confused with how some editors show last lines.

Comment: @fluffy Thank you very much. It seems that. I have another problem that when my list is null, I  want to write header to my csv file, but its result is an empty file. Do you know the reason?